# Azure Devops Api - how do i get a specified comment from a workitem?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I´m currently tryin to get a specified comment with a tag in a Workitem. like "[RN]Bla bla bla bla"

This tag in the comment should later be used for the release note description like "[RN] Fix for XYZ"

Has anyone ever done something like this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no search for comments. You may use rest API to get all comments in a work item: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/comments/get-comments?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP.

or consider using tags in work items directly... or use a separate field (new or existing) to store your build/release version. As an example, you may add the predefined field `Integration Build`:

[image]